# What values to use for linkExternalObject action on project object?

Tags: workfront-api

I'm trying to link external folder using Workfront API (v12) using linkExternalObject action on a project.
According to [Api Explorer](https://one.workfront.com/s/api-explorer) it takes 5 arguments:

- objID (string)
- linkedObjectID (string)
- integrationType (string)
- URL(string)
- params (string[])

This action is also described in [Developer Documentation](https://developer.workfront.com/projects.html#put-/proj/linkExternalObject), but that doesn't help much.

I'm assuming that:
objID will be id of a folder (DOCFDR) that I can create using api.
integrationType should be WEBHOOKS, since I'm integrating with external storage via document webhooks.

Any idea if it's correct way to create a linked folder and where to take the remaining values from?

I tried creating Linked Folder (LNKFDR) directly, but it's not a top level object so I can't.
I tried looking up values for Linked Folder created via Workfront UI but that doesn't help much.

[linkExternalObject action as documented in Api Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmZ15.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.